# Insert a line break automatically after 33 characters

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to insert a line break after every 33 characters typed.

**index.php**

```
<textbox id="txt"></textbox>
<div id="typing_view"></div>
```

**typeing.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txt').keyup(function(){
      $('#typing_view').html($(this).val());
    });
  });
```

so what the `js` file does is it displayes what ever i am typing but i want it to insert a line break after every 33 charaters

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex

```
$('#typing_view').html($(this).val().replace(/([\s\S]{33})/g, '$1<br />'));
```

**Regex Explanation:**

`([\s\S]{33})/g`: `()` is capturing group, the matches will be captured and can be accessed by using `$n`. `[\s\S]` matches **anything**. `{33}` is used to match exactly 33 characters of the previous match. `g` is global flag, without it only the first match will be matched.

`$1` refers to the first captured group i.e. 33 characters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txt').keyup(function() {
    $('#typing_view').html($(this).val().replace(/([\s\S]{33})/g, '$1<br />'));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<div id="typing_view"></div>
```

Comment: and can you explain whats happening in `replace(/([\s\S]{33})/g, '$1<br />'));` Please

Comment: @jake123 Sure, I've added explanation of regex.

Comment: How Would i prevent the use of html tags like when the user types i want it to display as text not as html using jquery Please Help

Comment: @jake123 Use `text`, `$('#typing_view').text(`